# finding specific solution to $u_{tt}-u_{xx}=x^2-t^2$ with boundry conditions $u(x,0)=\frac{-x^4}{16}-x, \ u_t(x,0)=1, x \in R$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I am analyzing  the following PDE 
$$u_{tt}-u_{xx}=x^2-t^2$$ 
with boundary conditions $$u(x,0)=\frac{-x^4}{16}-x, \quad u_t(x,0)=1, \quad x \in R$$

I understand how to derive the general solution no problem, just cannot figure out how to get the specific solution which supposed to be $\ \ \mathbf{u(x,t)=\frac{-(x^2-t^2)^2}{16}+t-x}$


I got the following general solution
$$u(x,t)=\frac{-(x^2-t^2)^2}{16}+F(x+t)+G(x-t)$$

applying the first condition $u(x,0)$
I get $$F(x)+G(x)=-x$$

applying second condition $u_t(x,0)=1$ I get
$$F'(x)+G'(x)=1$$

**how should this be continued? where the t (second term of the final specific solution) comes from?**

Comment: Did you check your result $u(x,t)=\frac{-(x^2+t^2)^2}{16}+F(x+t)+G(x-t)$ ? You just have to put it in the PDE and see if it agrees. You will see that there is a mistake.

Comment: this was a typo in Latex, I corrected it. I got the following equation using the correct general solution.

Comment: I mean I got $F(x)+G(x)=-x$ and $F'(x)+G'(x)=1$ but still cannot figure out how to get the final equation out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u(x,t)=\frac{-(x^2-t^2)^2}{16}+F(x+t)+G(x-t)$$

$$u_t=\frac{-(x^2-t^2)t}{4}+F'(x+t)-G'(x-t)$$

$\begin{cases}
u(x,0)=-\frac{x^4}{16}+F(x)+G(x)=-\frac{x^4}{16}-x \quad\to\quad F(x)+G(x)=-x \\
u_t(x,0)=F'(x)-G'(x)=1  \quad\to\quad F(x)-G(x)=x+c
\end{cases}$
$$\begin{cases}
F(x)=\frac{c}{2} \quad\to\quad F(x-t)=\frac{c}{2}\\
G(x)=-x-\frac{c}{2} \quad\to\quad G(x-t)=-(x-t)-\frac{c}{2}
\end{cases}$$
$u(x,t)=\frac{-(x^2-t^2)^2}{16}+\frac{c}{2}-(x-t)-\frac{c}{2}$
$$u(x,t)=\frac{-(x^2-t^2)^2}{16}-x+t$$